# How to make the tilt in HERE maps smoother?

Tags: heremaps

I am displaying a map using HERE maps, i have made a button (3D) to tilt the map to a certain angle when clicked.

this is code i use for tilting the map:

```js
function ChangeMapMode(btn) {
    if ($(btn).data('map-mode')) {
        mapGlobal.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
            tilt: 0,
            heading: 180,
        });
        $(btn).data('map-mode', false);
        $(btn).attr('title', "3D");
        $(btn).html('').html("3D");
    }
    else {
        mapGlobal.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
            tilt: 60,
        });
    }
}
```

This all works very well but the map tilts very qiuckly how can i make this transition smoother.

Comment: I found the solution, we can add animation using setLookAtData like this:
...setLookAtData({tilt : 60},true});
you can also add the speed to the animation as follow, 1.1 means 10% faster than default and 0.5 meaning 50% slower than default.